# How to Load DataGridView Fast

Tags: vb.net, dtgridview

How can I load my data view faster?? I only have less than 300 data but it loads at least 10 secs.

here is my code

```
Public Class frmPopupStockout
Private Sub tsSelect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tsSelect.Click
    Try
        With frmStockOut
            .txtPROCODE.Text = dtgList.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value
            Me.Close()
            .txtJOS.Focus()
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub FrmPopupStockout_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    query = "SELECT PROCODE as [Part Number - Location - Process], PName AS [Part Name],PNumber AS [Part Number], STOCKLOC AS [Location],PROQTY AS [Quantity], PROCS AS [Process] FROM  tblProductInfo"
    retrieve(query, dtgList)
End Sub

Private Sub txtSearch_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtSearch.TextChanged
    query = "SELECT PROCODE as [Part Number - Location - Process], PName AS [Part Name],PNumber AS [Part Number], STOCKLOC AS [Location],PROQTY AS [Quantity], PROCS AS [Process] FROM  tblProductInfo WHERE PROCODE LIKE '%" & txtSearch.Text & "%'"
    retrieve(query, dtgList)
End Sub

Private Sub tsClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tsClose.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

Here is the code on retrieve query

```
Public Sub retrieve(ByVal query As String, ByVal dtg As DataGridView)

    Try
        con.Open()
        cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        With cmd
            .Connection = con
            .CommandText = query
        End With

        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        da.SelectCommand = cmd

        dt = New DataTable
        da.Fill(dt)

        dtg.Columns.Clear()
        dtg.Columns.Add("count", "#")


        dtg.DataSource = dt
        Dim MAXROW As Integer = dt.Rows.Count - 1

        For i = 0 To MAXROW
            dtg.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = i
        Next
        With dtg
            .Columns(0).Width = 18
            '   .Columns(0).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter

            '.Columns(1).Visible = False
            .Font = New Font("arial", 8, FontStyle.Bold)
            .SelectionMode = False
        End With


    Catch ex As Exception
        logs(ex.Message & " at retrieve sub Procedure")
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Close()
        da.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

When ever I try to load the Form with data grid it freezes for a while then it will load the form together with data.

I am retrieving the data from MS Access database, which have the front end together with the application and the backend at the Network Shared Files.

Comment: 5 seconds the fastest.

Comment: So first question is which part off it takes the time?  Retrieving the data from the DB or displaying it in the datagrid.  By the query syntax I'm guessing your db is Access, have you reviewed that to see if there is any potential optimizations?  You've also neglicted to show us any code to either executing the query or displaying it in the Datagrid.  In addition, look at parameterizing your queries,  not sure about access, but there are performace gains in high end RDBM system

Comment: I don't see any code there that loads a `DataGridView` so, as it is, your question is a nonsense. Also, have you actually determined whether the grid is relevant at all, i.e. have you determined what proportion of time taken is spent retrieving data from the database and how much is loading that data into the grid? This question needs far more thought and effort from you before it is adequate.

Comment: If you have a MS Access database and you're storing the Connection object (trying to *re-use* it, somehow, when it's not really something your code can handle), then a high delay to load data in the UI is expected. It applies to other drivers, but with Access the *effect* is particularly nasty. - If the database is located in a networks share, of course even more.

Comment: Reedited my post

Comment: its function is to view the saved product (datagrid) then the user will select it, and its data will be automatically entered on the provided textbox after clicking select.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved
I set these 2 from AllCells to DisplayedCells or None (AutosizeColumnsMode and AutoSizeRowsMode. and viola it loads faster
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OARtU.png)